How do I edit a step function ASL to set a lambda function which is in a specific stack
I need to able to take a step functions ASL file and plugin my lambda which I am creating using CDK
For instance,
const myLambda = new NodeJSFunction(...)
const mySF = new StateMachine(this, 'sf-id', {
            stateMachineName: 'SM',
            definition: JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../src/step-functions/sf.asl'), 'utf8').toString()),

and the ASL has
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "first state",
  "States": {
    "first state": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "FunctionName": "" -**-> Need to plugin the physical id of my lambda (stack-mylambdalogicalid-awshash)**

      },
      ...

I could not find how to access the physical id a resource within CDK. Is there some other way to plugin the myLambda resource into the ASL while I am creating it?

You'd typically compose your definition with the CDK's state classes, not with ASL JSON.  Then pass myLambda.functionArn as a prop to the Task instance.  The CDK generates the ASL at synth-time.

Thanks @fedonev. I was trying to follow this post https://matthewbonig.com/posts/step-functions-and-the-cdk/ which makes it seem this is possible.

Update - Just using myLambda.functionArn in the asl works
